# Flex content not appearing when I use 11.5 flash player version

Tags: flash, apache-flex, google-chrome, version

for some reason, when I leave turned on the 11.5.31.2 of the player version in Chrome, but I turn off the rest, my Flex content doesnt show. I need to use a previous version, like 11.2.202.197.

Could it be a bug of the player or I have something wrong with my players/chrome?

Thanks.

Comment: this could happen for one of a million reasons.  Unfortunately, you are just going to do a lot of debugging / troubleshooting until you figure it out.  Comment things out in your code starting at the beginning as see if you can find the spot where it stops working in 11.5 in chrome.  Best.

Comment: Chrome started using the Pepper Flash plugin. I suggest you check your plugins list in chrome (chrome://plugins) and confirm whether the player in question has "pepper" in the path. If so give up :) Seriously though, that pepper flash plugin is buggy in so many ways. You can download and install the Flash plugin directly from Adobe if this is the case.

Comment: @Sunil yep, the PPAPI version is the one who is not working, the NPAPI works.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is using his own version of flash player plugin.
disable it chrome://plugins/ and enable adobe version.. should help